# How do I accept TCP and UDP?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

Im trying to implement both TCP and UDP in my server. I can accept a TCP or UDP port connection from a client.

for example, I want to have code to accept TCP and UDP in one program:

```html
# create a socket
sockTCP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #TCP
sockUDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP


# server address to connect to
server_addressTCP = ('localhost', tcp_port)
server_addressUDP = ('localhost', udp_port)


# bind socket to adress and port number 
sockTCP.bind(server_addressTCP)
sockUDP.bind(server_addressUDP)


# wait for connections (clients)
print("Waiting for connections...")
print(" ")
sockTCP.listen(20)

request = ''

while True:
    #TCP
 client_sock, client_addr = sockTCP.accept()
    data, addr = client_sock.recvfrom(1024)

    #UDP
    udp_data, udp_addr = sockUDP.recvfrom(1024)

    # DO SOMETHING WITH DATA.........

    client_sock.close()
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection, and theefore no such thing as accepting one either.

Comment: have a look at the `selectors` module (or just use `select`). they can be used as a signal in your code to either accept a new TCP connection or receive a UDP datagram

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a server that listens on UDP and TCP then create listener threads: one for UDP and one for TCP connections.

Here is an example of a server listening on both TCP and UDP ports.

```python
import socket
import threading

tcp_port = udp_port = 1234

def udp_listen(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if len(data) != 0:
            print("recv:", data)

def tcp_listen(sock):
    while True:
        conn, _ = sock.accept()
        try:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if len(data) == 0:
                    break
                print("recv:", data)
        except Exception:
            pass
        try:
            conn.close()
        except Exception:
            pass

# create a socket
sockTCP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # TCP
sockUDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)   # UDP

# server address to connect to
server_addressTCP = ('localhost', tcp_port)
server_addressUDP = ('localhost', udp_port)

# bind socket to adress and port number 
sockTCP.bind(server_addressTCP)
sockUDP.bind(server_addressUDP)

sockTCP.listen(20)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=tcp_listen, args=(sockTCP,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=udp_listen, args=(sockUDP,))

print("Waiting for connections...")

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```